# how to connect saml appid on ibm cloud with ReactJS application?

Tags: reactjs, ibm-cloud, saml, app-id, ibm-appid

someone have an idea, how to connect saml appid on ibm cloud with ReactJS application ? if any body have a link or doc about that i'm gratefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App ID is a service provider that you can use to federate users via SAML. To do so, you have to set up your SAML identity provider in your App ID instance, following these instructions https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-enterprise .

Once your SAML IDP is set up, you can integrate App ID in your application, using the SDKs or APIs. Please refer to the documentation for more information https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-web-apps&interface=ui

The SAML assertion is handled by App ID, so once the integration is successful, your application users will be authorized via oAuth/OIDC through App ID